# JPA mappedBy don't persisting entity with relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

For example, I have the following entities:
Room entity:

```
@Entity
public class Room extends Base {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
private List<Person> persons;
//getters and setters
}
```

And the Person entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Base {

@ManyToOne
private Room room;

private String name;
//getters and setters
}
```

If I add person to room's persons list and then persist, the room is added, but person is not. I thought, enough is to add `mappedBy` parameter to `OneToMany` annotation, but.. what should I do else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the opposite, set a `Room` as the *room* field of a `Person` instance:

```
Room room = ...;
person.setRoom(room);
// persist the person
```

With the `mappedBy`, you specify that *which entity owns the relationship*. Updating the relationship between those two entities is *the responsibility of the owning side*.

In your example, the `Person` owns the relationship, so it's his responsibility to update the foreign key, not `Room`'s, so when you add a `Person` to list of persons in `Room` and update the `Room`, `Room` wouldn't update the foreign key for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `CascadeType=PERSIST or ALL` on `@OneToMany`. And Also set `room` variable in `Person` class to populate foreign key in Person table.

Comment: I really need to set this variable? JPA can't populate fk itself looking on mappedBy? This is only what I need